# Zend with doctrine and factory

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I use zend on my company but i have never started setting it up.
I downloaded the framework and want to integrate doctrine... I tried to get the doctrine object using getServiceLocator() but on zend 2x it will be deprecated and when I try to do this:

```
 public function indexAction()
 {
     $em = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
 }
```

I get the following exceptions:

> 1 - An exception was raised while creating
>   "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager"; no instance returned 2 - An abstract
>   factory could not create an instance of
>   doctrine.entitymanager.ormdefault(alias:
>   doctrine.entitymanager.orm_default).

So I tried to pass the doctrine object by factory... but the factory is never called.
That's what I did:

```
 'controllers' => array(
        'invokables' => array(
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumController'
        ),
        'factories' => [
            'Album\Controller\Album' => 'Album\Controller\AlbumControllerFactory'
        ]
    ),
```

On module.php

```
public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return [
            'factories' => [
                '\Album\Controller\Album' => function() {
                    exit;
                }
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Nothing that I do seems to get inside the factory class.

```
class AlbumControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        exit;
    }
    public function createService(\Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator) {
        exit;
        /* @var $serviceLocator \Zend\Mvc\Controller\ControllerManager */
        $sm   = $serviceLocator->getServiceLocator();
        $em = $sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        $controller = new AlbumController($em);
        return $controller;
    }
}

class AlbumController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $em = $this->getServiceLocator()
            ->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
```

Here is how my structure looks like:

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mapping of your classes are wrong for your `AlbumController` as you use `Album\Controller\Album` instead of `Album\Controller\AlbumController`. Use the FQCN (*Fully Qualified Class Name*).

For your module.php, there is a '\' infront of the class name, aswell you forgot the Controller at the end.

```php
use Album\Controller\AlbumController;
use Album\Controller\AlbumControllerFactory;

class Module implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    /**
     * Expected to return \Zend\ServiceManager\Config object or array to seed
     * such an object.
     * @return array|\Zend\ServiceManager\Config
     */
    public function getControllerConfig()
    {
        return [
            'aliases' => [
                'Album\Controller\Album' => AlbumController::class,
            ],
            'factories' => [
                AlbumController::class => AlbumControllerFactory::class,
            ]
        ];
    }
```

Comment: It worked actually. Thanks! But I had another problem... the database password was empy and zend stacks all the exceptions. So the last exception at the end of the page was invalid password. I fixed it and it worked.

Comment: how about to pass it to the model??
I created a model under /Album/Model/Diver and on my module.php I did 
`public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return [
            'aliases' => [
                'Album\Model\Diver' => Diver::class,
            ],
            'factories' => [
                Diver::class => DiverFactory::class
            ]
        ];
    }`
But the class DiverFactory is not called, nothing happens

Comment: Either call your service within your controllers or factories with the ServiceManager either like: `$serviceManager->get('Album\Model\Diver')` or `$serviceManager->get(Diver::class)`. Notice that the alias is pretty useless as it is the same as the FQCN (*Object::class*), so probaly referencing to itsself instead of the factory. Change the alias or remove it. And another tip is to stick with FQCN, so that when you refactor and move your class, it changes aswell and you don't have to edit every config which mentions it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tips... But I think I did not make myself clear.
I don't want to call the model on the controller. That's I know how to do!
I want to instantiate the serviceManager in the model. I tried using the Factory but it does not call DiverFactory